# Best way to redirect http to https on ELB with IIS

Tags: http, iis, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

Whats the best way to redirect http traffic to https on a ELB with IIS ??  I have 3 options

- Redirect at DNS level (using forwarder) from my domain
  provider(Godaddy)
- Redirect at AWS using IIS web.config's `<system.webServer><rewrite><rules>` section
- Use Cloudfront to redirect http to https, but there is a cost involved.

Right now,  my site works on both http and https separately.  On ELB, no port is assigned to http and only HTTPS site is kept activated.
[image: ELB Config]

Whats the best way to redirect http traffic to https from above two options?? Is there any better way then these 2 options to achieve this redirection??

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, but I would suggest you to add a **Rewrite** rule in **IIS**. This is easier to manage in case you plan to add additional domains to your site. **Domain Forwarding** may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 sounds the best.

Add http and https listeners on your ELB.

Then add redirect rules in IIS.

Comment: Will the redirect rules in ISS work during  autoscaling and when new instances are auto created ??

Comment: Yes set the redirect using all the same host and path args, only changing the protocol. Since your LB is listening on both ports and from the same domain, it will still work.

Comment: Ok,  I have also checked the cloudfront route to achieve this, but there is a cost involved.  Im going to add this option on the question.